# Shake method iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am using iPhone sdk's motionended method to get the shake effect on 3.0.

The problem I am having is that the it works find on the first shake which I play a view, but once the video finished and I shake the device again it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something else, like the video player, may have become the first responder after the first time you shake the device.  This could be preventing the shake events from getting to your view or controller.  You may need to manually restore the first responder status to the element handling the shake by sending it `-becomeFirstResponder` once the video has finished.

Comment: I tries [self becomefirstresponse] on videodidfinsih method, but no effect. ANything else I can try or I am doing wrong

Comment: You may also have to override -(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder and return YES.  Otherwise, you may need to place the call to becomeFirstResponder later.

Comment: Yes I do already have the override -(BOOL) can becomefirstresponder and Returning YES